# Why does the special character ( " ) in a configurable product name change to 'quot'?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, special-character

> I have created a configurable product with the name of **Test -"config** (screenshot) and created configuration and add color attribute then it is working perfectly, but when second time edit that product then that special character (" )  is changing to **quot** (screenshot) but on frontend product name is showing perfectly but in backend product name is showing with the **quot** , is't issue of magento ? can anyone please explain this ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`&quot;` is the html entity name for a quotation mark. The browser will render html entities correctly on the frontend as you've noted but when it comes to that form input magento is either running an ecapeHtml call or saving it as the entity version rather than escaping the character.

It shouldn't cause a problem if you can live with it.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_entities.htm

Comment: Got it but if I remove ecapeHtml then it is showing product name perfectly in backend, so if I remove ecapeHtml  , is there any problem would be occur ?